# NSLog prints a string different to the NSString with format

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring, nslog

This is something that I'm truly baffled by: when I initialize a string with format with two different variables like this

```
Order *o = [orders objectAtIndex:i];
NSString *line = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:(@"%@;%@\n", [o _length], [o _amount])];
```

and then print it out with

```
NSLog(@"%@", line);
```

it shows up like this:

```
tableviewtest[4812:123250] 200
```

Which is wrong. However if I do the same by doing this

```
NSLog(@"%@;%@\n", [o _length], [o _amount]);
```

it comes out like this:

```
tableviewtest[4812:123250] 120cm;200
```

Which is how I'd WANT the `line` to be. Why is this happening? I need it to be in the same format as the `line` so that I can then write it into a text file later.

**EDIT:**

`_length` and `_amount` are `@property NSString *_length` in an Order-class. `orders` is an `NSMutableArray` that houses the data to an `NSTableView`, where the data is put in with NSComboBoxes and NSTextFields. Compiler also gives a warning: Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure).

Comment: I'd check the code once more. Given the choice that iOS or MacOS X shows some bizarre behaviour that I have never seen, or that you made a trivial mistake, I'd assume the latter.

Comment: Your first NSLog is not of the result from that `initWithFormat` call, but comes from somewhere else.

Comment: (And we have no idea how you've declared `_length` and `_amount`.)

Comment: What do you get, if you try `-localizedStringWithFormat:…`?

Comment: OK, as Schemetrical points out, the immediate problem is that you put `( )` around the entire argument list for `initWithFormat`.  But there are several other problems -- using `initWithFormat`, using leading `_` for property names, and (in writing your question) failing to provide full context.  (And likely you ignored a compiler warning.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 

`NSString *line = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:(@"%@;%@\n", [o _length], [o _amount])];`, 
use 
`NSString *line = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@;%@\n", [o _length], [o _amount]];`

Comment: Also, you can do o._length and o._amount, but its common for properties to not use the underscore because those are reserved for backing ivars.

Comment: That won't fix his problem, of course, but it's the correct approach.

Comment: @HotLicks I think the way he grouped his format string, it ignored the first couple params and printed the last. `-initWithFormat:` takes multiple params, he passes a paren with many variables, which confuses the compiler.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right!! Zoomed right past the parens.  (Very likely there was a compiler warning that the OP ignored.)

Comment: @HotLicks yeah I was wondering why I haven't seen that syntax before 

Comment: Thank you Schemetrical, that sorted it out!

Comment: @SMoi dont forget that properties shouldn't begin with an underscore as those are reserved for ivars :-), good luck!

Answer (score 2):

@Schemetrical is correct, but it is not a compiler confusion. It is a behavior defined in the C standard. Let's have the original source code:

```
NSString *line = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:(@"%@;%@\n", [o _length], [o _amount])];
```

The arg list is build from

```
(@"%@;%@\n", [o _length], [o _amount])
```

This is a expression build from comma operators following the C standard, 6.5.17.. That means that

```
@"%@;%@\n", [o _length]
```

is evaluated as

```
((void)@"%@;%@\n")
expr = [o _length]
```

returning expr. Then

```
(expr, [o _amount])
```

is evaluated as

```
((void)expr)
expr = [o _amount])
```

This is the result of the expression used as single argument:

```
NSString *line = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:_amount];
```

Therefore the whole statement is pretty good C/Objective-C code. The only reason to show a warning is that the format arg is not a constant. (But this is definitely not what went wrong.)